# Recursive query comprehensions (F# 3.0)

Tags: f#

I am trying to define Bill Of Materials kind of queries using the recently introduced F# 3.0 query comprehension syntax. Though it is possible to define these kind of queries using `yield!` seq comprehensions for in-memory collections I had no lack in translating those into query comprehensions that target remotable IQueryable sources. I guess the hard part would be  to "train" the provider into recognizing Common Table Expressions out of recursive patterns.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't wish to be nasty but if you're planning to post here again, you may wish to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures  You don't need a signature or tagline and in fact it's sort of discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I don't think that the current query syntax support in F# 3.0 is capable of dealing with recursive queries. The main problem is that F# 3.0 relies on standard `IQueryable` implementations that were designed mainly for C# and so they do not expect recursive structures.

I think that supporting this would be quite difficult. You could either implement your own F# quotations to SQL translator (which is hard) or you could implement some sort of pre-processor that takes an F# quotation (query) that contains recursion and translates the recursion to something that the LINQ to SQL translator can deal with (but this is probably hard too).

In general, the approach would be to define your own query builder:

```
open System.IO
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type MyQueryBuilder() =
  member x.For(a, body) = Seq.collect body a
  member x.Quote(e) = e
  member x.YieldFrom(s) = s
  member x.Run(e:Expr<'T>) : 'T = failwithf "%A" e

// Example using the custom query builder
// (fails, printing the quoted query)
let mquery = MyQueryBuilder()    
let n = [1 .. 10]

let rec nums a : seq<int> =
  mquery { for b in n do
           yield! nums b }
```

In the `Run` method, you get a quotation that represents the query. You could pre-process that and replace all calls to `MyQueryBuilder` with calls to standard `query` operations and replace recursion with something else. Then you could call `query.Run` (to run the standard `IQueryable` implementation).

Though as I said, this is probably going to be quite difficult to implement - but perhaps, if you have some specific kind of recursion that you can easily deal with, it might be an option. However, if LINQ to SQL does not generate Common Table Expressions for any standard patterns, then I don't think you can train it to generate them - as far as I know, the translator is not really extensible.